# Curious as to why this line matters so much for the rest of the function to work properly

Tags: python, python-3.x

Initially when I wrote the function I didn't include `print(UserInput.users)` within the `set_list`function , however, I thought that it would be helpful for a list to show the user which lists they have the ability to create. After I removed it, the function didn't work properly:

```
class UserInput:
    users=[]

    def __init__(self, name,lista,listb,listc,listd):
        self.name=""
        self.lista=lista
        self.listb=listb
        self.listc=listc
        self.listd=listd

    @classmethod
    def create_new_users(cls):
        print("how many users do you want to create")
        x=int(input())
        for _ in range(x):       
            print("assign the users names")
            name = input()
            if name == '' or name.lower()  == 'none':
                raise RuntimeError("name cannot be None or empty")              
            user=cls(name,"","","","")      
            cls.users.append(name)
        return(name)

    @classmethod  
    def show_users(cls):
        print(UserInput.users)

    def set_lists():
        print("Do you want to create lists")
        decision = input()
        print( "select the user you intend on adding lists for")
        #why does the function require the code print(UserInput.users) on this line to   function properly?
        choice = input()
        for elem in UserInput.users:
            if choice == elem:
                if decision == "yes":   
                    print("how many lists would you like to create?(up to 4)")
                    decision2= int(input())
                    if decision2 == 1:
                        print("what would you like the list to be named?")
                        self.lista=input()
                        print("you have created 1 list, with the name:"+ self.lista)                                         

                    elif decision2 == 2:
                        print("what would you like your lists to be?")
                        self.lista,self.listb=input().split(",")
                        print("You have created 2 lists with the names," + self.lista ,self.listb)

                    elif decision2 == 3:
                        print("what name would you like your lists to be?")
                        self.lista,self.listb,self.listc = input().split(",")

                        print("you have created 3 lists with the names," +self.lista,self.listb,self.listc)
                    elif decision2 == 4:
                        print("what name would you lists to be?")
                        self.lista,self.listb,self.listc,self.listd = input().split(",")

                        print("you have created 4 lists with the names of," +self.lista,self.listb,self.listc,self.listd)
                    else:
                        print("quitting")
                        return


            else:
                print("not in users list")
                break
```

**My Question:** When `print(UserInput.users)` is included in the function it will recognize the list if I choose a name from it but if its not included it skips to the else at the bottom: Why?

Comment: I'd bet on indentation errors. Maybe you are mixing tabs and spaces.

Comment: @rodrigo you say that as if you know exactly where? I'm pretty sure everything is nested correctly within the function and if you were referring to the `users=[]`, that was a copy/paste issue that I had to fix here its all indented correctly within my file

Comment: Please specify in what way it "stopped working" when you removed that line.

Comment: it didn't stop working BrenBarn, it just skipped to the bottom of the function to else statement when I inputted a valid user list name the answer is the else statement I accidently deleted, ive already flagged this question so a mod can delete it; its a useless question. I thought I had a valid problem and I dont

Answer (score 1):

Searching through your code revealed at least one instance of mixed tabs and spaces. That could be the problem, but I doubt it. Instead, I suspect it's a logic error that has nothing to do with the line you removed.

```
    for elem in UserInput.users:
        if choice == elem:
            stuuuuuuuuuff...
        else:
            print("not in users list")
            break
```

If the `choice` is not the first element of `UserInput.users`, this will hit the `else` clause on the first iteration and break. I suspect you only want to do that if the `choice` isn't in the list at all. Instead of looping, I recommend the `in` operator:

```
if choice in UserInput.users:
    stuuuuuuuuuuff...
else:
    print("Not in user list.")
```

Comment: im just going to delete this question now, I thought I had a valid problem;however I just solved it. It was one else statement I forgot I accidently deleted